# ¿Cómo puedo desactivar el botón de un formulario mientras se procesa una petición Ajax en Javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo una función que recoge datos de un formulario y los manda al servidor, pero en algunos casos, los datos se están mandando dos veces, imagino que es porque el servidor tarda un poco y los usuarios pulsan dos veces en el botón `dv-subscribe`.

¿Cómo podría prevenir esto? Imagino que desactivando el botón desde la primera vez que es enviado. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? He visto ejemplos, pero todos basados en jQuery. No quiero usar librerías, sino Javascript puro.

Esta es mi función:

```
function logSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var mFName=document.getElementById("dv-fname");
    var mLName=document.getElementById("dv-lname");
    var mEmail=document.getElementById("dv-email");
    var mButton=document.getElementById("dv-subscribe");
    var mInfo=document.getElementById("info");
    var toPost=`mFName=${mFName.value}&mLName=${mLName.value}&mEmail=${mEmail.value}`;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var msgInfo='Ocurrió un error, intenta más tarde o ponte en contacto conmigo por email:\n ***';
    //mInfo.innerHTML=msgInfo;

    req.open('POST', ajax_var.url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if(req.status == 200){
                //alert(msgInfo);                   
              msgInfo=req.responseText;
              mFName.value="";
              mLName.value="";
              mEmail.value="";
              
            }
            alert(msgInfo);
            //mInfo.innerHTML=msgInfo;
        };
    }
    req.send(toPost);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes ya el botón en la variable `mButton`, úsala para desactivarlo:

```
mButton.disabled = true;
```

En la función de respuesta puedes volver a activarlo:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
  mButton.disabled = false;
  ...
};
```

Comment: Gracias. He intentando tu código, pero por algún motivo el botón no se bloquea (Safari). Probé dándole click varias veces y la petición de procesa N veces.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo estas poniendo antes de hacer la petcion? Porque en si la estructura esta bien `buttonObject.disabled = true|false `

Comment: Estoy poniendo el `true` justo después de declarar el elemento: `var mButton=document.getElementById("dv-subscribe"); mButton.disabled = true;` y dentro de este bloque `req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {` estoy poniendo el `false`, @JuanRivera.

Answer (score 1):

Como ya habian dicho anteriormente para desabilitar un `button` solamente es poner el `disabled` y este debe estar seleccionado con algo, en este caso el `id`:

```js
function DesabilitarBTN() {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
}

function HabilitarBTN() {
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .democlass {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="HabilitarBTN()">Habilitar</button><br><br>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <button type="submit" onclick="DesabilitarBTN()" id="btn">Desabilitar</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Pero tambien existe otra forma de hacerlo, que es agregando el atributo `disabled` en el mismo button y quitando el atributo cuando se quiere habilitar

```js
function DesabilitarBTN() {
  event.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("btn").setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}

function HabilitarBTN() {
  document.getElementById("btn").removeAttribute("disabled", "false");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .democlass {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="HabilitarBTN()">Habilitar</button><br><br>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <button type="submit" onclick="DesabilitarBTN()" id="btn">Desabilitar</button>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Ambas funcionan correctamente, pero para esto es mejor utilizar la primera opcion, en cuanto a tu caso que no funciona en `Safari`, deberia hacerlo porque si es compatible con el navegador

Comment: Ahora funciona. El problema era que estoy agregando el JS desde Wordpress y olvidé actualizar la versión del archivo, en cuyo caso carga una versión antigua del mismo sin el código actualizado. Gracias de todos modos.